# secure http calls in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

How do I secure http call everytime I fire from my app and also it needs to have timeout so that any other user cannot use the same link from any browser.

I am looking for ios solution in particular and not html form.

Please help me out. Unable to resolve this issue and dont know in which direction to proceed.

Thanks in Advance.

I am attaching Working code for both PHP and ios which posts the Request and gets back the Response but no security is attached and any user can get the same Response by calling the same HTTP Response from Browser anytime...

ios code:

```
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/getmsgs/strno=123"];

    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    connection=[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if(connection){

        webData=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    }


NSError *requestError = NULL;

NSDictionary *allData=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webdata options:0 error:&requestError];


if (requestError){
    //An error occurred.
    NSLog(@"error is : %@",requestError);
}

if (! allData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", requestError);
} else {
    NSLog(@" data is : %@",allData) ;
}



NSArray *arrayOfEntry=[allData objectForKey:@"json"];

for (NSDictionary *diction in arrayOfEntry) {


    NSString *label=[title objectForKey:@"image"];

    NSString *label2=[title objectForKey:@"artist"];

    NSString *label3=[title objectForKey:@"name"];

    [array addObject:label];
        [array addObject:label2];
            [array addObject:label3];

}
```

php code:

```
<?php

    $strno=$_GET['strno'];

    if (isset($strno))
    {
            $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","test","test") or die ('Connection error!!!');
            mysql_select_db("test") or die ('Database error!!!');

        $query=mysql_query("select sno FROM users  where strno='$strno';");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

        {
            $jsonoutput='{"json":{
                "image":"'.$row['image'].'",
"artist":"'.$row['artist'].'",
"name":"'.$row['name'].'"
                }}';
        }

    }

    echo trim($jsonoutput);
    mysql_close($connect) or die ('Unable to close connection-error!!!');
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of session to achieve what you want. For example, when user opens(runs) your ios app, you could connect to your web-service to get the session key (token), which would be unique for the device that app is running. And, when your ios app goes to the background, you could invalidate the token (using ios background execution would be appropriate here). Also, you could use time-limited session keys, meaning for example your session key will expire in 10 mins (which get invalidated on the server side), and for the new web requests your server has to issue another session key. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank You Sir for your response.Can you edit the code above with your explanation .It would be of a great help.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: James, what I'm saying would a lot of codes, that's why I can't provide the code. But main idea here is that on your server side you have device authentication method, which takes device unique string(maybe some more parameters like time stamp etc. depending on your implementation) as a parameter and generates the unique session key and returns to the ios app. All future requests to the server would have that unique string(session key) as a parameter, so that server can identify the device. That would some basic security for your requests to the server.

Comment: what happens if someone else knows that unique string he can use that string and paste the link with the unique string in browser and still proceed with the following request.Can I stop that too??

Comment: perhaps you can share a link to  example/project which uses the above description as you have mentioned.That would help me greatly to implement and I could get back to you after that with further queries .Greatly appreciate your help.